# How to get a code reference from a object method using Moo

Tags: perl, moo, coderef

I'm using Moo (OO) under Perl v5.26 and Linux.

I'm writing tests and have some kind of runtime dictionary in an object to store states of an application. I want to test if a defined code reference points to the adequate method in that object.

My problem is to find the right expression for this test.

```perl
# Struggle point 
ok($exitFun == \$TK->exitError);

diag($exitFun," ");          # OK    .. CODE(0x55a8a9027808) 
diag(\$TK->exitError,"\n");  # ERROR .. Too few args for AppTK::exitError
```

### Details

The application toolkit is initialized by several steps during the runtime to standardize some things. Here is the setup:

```perl
# ---------------------------------------------------
# Support variables
# ----------------------------------------------------
my $TOOL    = 'TEST.TOOL';
my $MAGIC   = 'TEST.MAGIC';
my $IOTYPE  = 'ASCII.DICT';
my $VERSION = 'VERSION';
my $AUTHOR  = 'AUTHOR';
my $CONTACT = 'CONTACT';
my $OUTPUT  = 'TEST.CASE';
my $RES_ERROR = 'ERROR';

# Some paremter with certain types
my $OPT_STR  = 'OPT_STR';
my $OPT_INT  = 100;
my $OPT_REAL = 1.8;
my $OPT_BOOL = 0;
my $OPT_DATE = '2021-11-12';
my $OPT_TOOL = `which bash`;
chomp($OPT_TOOL);
my @PARAM = qw(--tool $OPT_TOOL --bool $OPT_BOOL --STR  $OPT_STR
               --INT  $OPT_INT  --REAL $OPT_REAL --DATE $OPT_DATE
               --output +OUTPUT --response ERROR);

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Command environment setup
# -----------------------------------------------------
# Command 
my $COMMAND = 'command1';

# Command Parameter Brancher 
my $COMMANDS = {
                  # Assoc. sub for the command 
    $COMMAND => [ \&testCommant,
                  # Parameter set for the sub
                  { INT  => $OPT_INT  ,
                    STR  => $OPT_STR  ,
                    BOOL => $OPT_BOOL ,
                    DATE => $OPT_DATE ,
                    REAL => $OPT_REAL ,
                    TOOL => $OPT_TOOL },
              ],
};

# Create a new application object
$TK->new;

# Init Application Context 
ok($TK->initApplication($VERSION, $DATE, $AUTHOR, $CONTACT))
...
# Init Runtime context before parsing the CLI data
ok($TK->initRuntime($MAGIC, $TOOL, $IOTYPE, \@PARAM),
   "Init runtime set");
...
# Set runtime parameter before calling the command brancher 
# to run a certein sub routine with a defined parameter set.
ok($TK->setRuntime($COMMANDS, $OUTPUT, $RES_ERROR, $COMMAND));
```

`setRuntime` sets $TK internal an `exitFunc`  depending on the variable $RESPONSE.

- `$RESPONSE = 'ERROR'` links the method `$exitFun = \&exitError is $TK->exitError`.
- `$RESPONSE = 'WARN'`  links the method `$exitFun = \&exitWarn  is $TK->exitWarn`.

Within the test suite I want test which `$exitFun` (CODE REFERENCE) is given back by `$TK->getRuntimeValues`.

```perl
# Check what was stored
my ( $tool, $output, $response,
     $command, $exitFun, $param ) = $TK->getRuntimeValues; 
ok($tool     eq $TOOL);      # OK
ok($output   eq $OUTPUT);    # OK
ok($response eq $RES_ERROR); # OK
ok($command  eq $COMMAND);
...

# Struggle point 
ok($exitFun == \$TK->exitError);

diag($exitFun,"\n");         # OK    .. CODE(0x55a8a9027808) 
diag(\$TK->exitError,"\n");  # ERROR .. Too few args for AppTK::exitError
```

It seem that the test tries to call the method. What is the right expression for the test to get the CODE REF from the method beyond `$TK->`?

#### Edit Definition:

Within the package `AppTK` the relation is defined by a dictionary:

```perl
my %EXITS = (
    FATAL => \&exitFatal,    # Response that signals a failure
    WARN  => \&exitWarn,     # Response that signals a warning
    ERROR => \&exitError,    # Response that signals a Error
    INFO  => \&exitInfo,     # Response that signals a Info
);
...
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
sub exitRuntime ( $self, $error, $remarks = '', $example = '' ) {
    my $exitFun = $self->runtime->{ +CONST::KEY_EXIT_FUN };
    &$exitFun( $self, $error, $remarks, $example );
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
sub exitError ( $self, $message, $remarks = '', $example = '' ) {
    exitStatus( $self, 'E', $message, $remarks, $example );
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
sub exitFatal ( $self, $message, $remarks = '', $example = '' ) {
    exitStatus( $self, 'F', $message, $remarks, $example );
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
sub exitInfo ( $self, $message, $remarks = '', $example = '' ) {
    exitStatus( $self, 'I', $message, $remarks, $example );
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
sub exitCancel ( $self, $message, $remarks = '', $example = '' ) {
    exitStatus( $self, 'C', $message, $remarks, $example );
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
sub exitWarn ( $self, $message, $remarks = '', $example = '' ) {
    exitStatus( $self, 'W', $message, $remarks, $example );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a sub in the `AppTK` package named `getRuntimeValues` that sometimes returns `\&exitError`, and you want to check if that's what it did.

To do this, you can compare against the following:

```perl
\&AppTK::exitError      # The sub returned by `\&exitError` from package `AppTK`
```

While not strictly equivalent, the following will produce the same result if `$TK` is blessed into `AppTK`:

```perl
$TK->can("exitError")   # The sub called by `$TK->exitError`
```

Comment: `ok($exitFun == \&TAppK::exitError );` works perfect.